Does equipping both a Familiar and the Gathering Tool they emulate, increase the Gathering Spot type occurance rate more than either alone?
Was going to use Toula to bypass the fishing minigame, but kept forgetting to unequip the Rod Of Fishing.
The Wiki says that an unupgraded Toula makes Fishing Spots have a 25% of occurring.
I've only used her with the Rod of Fishing for 2 nights, but it does seem that using Familiar and Tool together increases Gathering chances, but is it really so?
